# How do return Java List<String> Json using Jax-RS

Tags: java, json, string, list, jaxb2

I'd like know how do to a method return a JSON array of List, for example:

```
@GET 
@Produces("application/json")
public List<String> aMethod(){
  return Array.asList("text1", "text2", "text3");
}
```

I'd want to know, how do to receive a List argument type in my method, for example

```
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json") void otherMethod(List<String>){
   // do something ;
}
```

I've read about JaxbContext, I understanding how it can help me.

Comment: JAXB is for XML, are you confusing it with JAX-RS?

Comment: Ok, but how do i for return a List<String> with jax-rs?

Comment: @user268396 no, JAX-B can be used to automatically serialize/deserialize data coming in and out of a JAX-RS web service.

Comment: I only want to know how is possible or whether is possible to return or  receive a List<String> with jax-rs

Comment: @Oleksi: JAXB is specifically designed for producing/consuming XML (Java Architecture for XML Binding, after all). However, there is a library (Jettison) which lets you parse and emit JSON through a StaX implementation. The point being: JAXB does not have any concept of JSON, so any support for JSON relies on retrofitting JSON to an XML model of the world (StaX).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With JAXB there are two type's of `List` supported. The first is a List of elements, the second a delimited string (a "normal" XML value or attribute, which is parsed into a list using some delimiter). The first seems to be what you want ("array").

For reference, see: http://jaxb.java.net/jaxb20-ed/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlList.html

You will note that in both cases the List you want would need to be encapsulated by some other object. Fundamentally, XML (and by extension JAXB) likes to trace everything back to a single root node/object. So to model it, you need something like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="wrapper")
public abstract class ListWrapper {
   public List<String> names;
}
```

Then your methods would need to be changed to accept/return `ListWrapper` objects and extract the actual List from it.

Comment: I already did imagine that don't was  possible return directly a List<String>. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same without success, so I ended with packing a string into one field object.

```
return listWithString
                .stream()
                .map(
                        stringElement -> {
                            MyBoxObject bo = new MyBoxObject();
                            bo.setSomeField(stringElement);
                            return bo;
                        })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```