# How to return List<String> as Response in JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, gson

I have read many articles to return `List<String>`
things which I tried are:

**1.** GenericEntity (getting Internal server error)

**2.** GSON (getting only string)

Can anyone please help me how to return `List<String>` as a response in **JAX-RS**?

**Note:** I am using `Jersey`.

I have tried below code it is working for XML response but not for JSON response

```
@XmlRootElement(name="List")
public class JAXBList<T> {

    protected List<T> list;

    public JAXBList(){}

    public JAXBList(List<T> list){
        this.list=list;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="Item")
    public List<T> getList(){
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145873/how-do-return-java-liststring-json-using-jax-rs

Comment: Thanks Aurashere, but That is no working . i already tried that

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: I have posted Aurasphere Can you please look and let me know

Comment: Are you getting some errors? If so, please show them. They will help

Comment: I can see only 500 - Internal server Error. Do you have any Idea about this?

Comment: @Sahil can you try jackson?  I think it is the best provider you can find

Comment: Thanks varren, Jackson helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Jackson to get List. I am able to Return List using Jackson.
As String is inbuilt Class so doesn't support by jersey to return String.
So Explicitly we need to do it from Jackson.