# Returning list of values in Restful webservices

Tags: java, json, rest

I am working on a small example where I want to return list of values from my webservice:

```
@GET
@Path("/string")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<String> test2()
{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("USA");
    list.add("EGYPT");
    return list;
}
```

I am able to get response by calling this service successfully.

```
List list1 = client.target("http://localhost:8080/services/customers/string")
                   .request()
                   .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                   .get(List.class);
```

It gives me data as `[USA, EGYPT]`

But it seems we need to use GenericEntity as per this post - [Jersey: Return a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392413/jersey-return-a-list-of-strings)

or as a wrapper class - [How do return Java List<String> Json using Jax-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145873/how-do-return-java-liststring-json-using-jax-rs)

When we need to use these 2 options? Is it required to use GenericEntity or Wrapper classes?

I am using JAX-RS2.0 with Jersey implementation.

Comment: As far as I know it's not required, but wrapping it inside of a `ResponseEntity` for instance allows you add additional parameters such a html status.

Comment: The below link could help you figure it out [A message body writer for Java class java.util.ArrayList…and MIME media type text/xml was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41429076/8228918)

Answer (score 0):

The serialization of your response is done by a jersey entity provider according to [a specific algorithm](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#providers-selection). You should have a default provider in the context of your application supporting the serialization of your instance of List. Thus you do not need further wrapping.